# Add a Foreign Key to a Populated MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I need to add a foreign key to a table already populated with data ...

```
CREATE TABLE `clientes` (
  `id_cliente` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_cashback` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `cashback00` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `valor` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE clientes ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cliente_cashback FOREIGN KEY (id_cashback) REFERENCES cashback(id)
```

ALTER TABLE only works if the parent table (customers) is not populated.

If it already has data, how to proceed since ALTER TABLE presents error "error no. 150" Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed "

Comment: We can not see the cashback table(REFERENCES cashback(id)) or you wanted to do this: REFERENCES cashback00(id) ?

Comment: It works fine if the foreign key references are valid:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=83c51acbba4c94a380bd2e7c74532b90.

Comment: @John, also, it is a nice thing to reply to the people who helped you with answers and comments...

Comment: I understood your answer now ... that's right @GordonLinoff 

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your help, but I managed to solve the problem:

SGBD integrity issue ...

see, if you want to add a foreign key to a populated parent table, the column must also be populated, like this:

```
UPDATE clientes
SET id_cashback = '1'
WHERE id_cliente >= '1' AND id_cliente <= '3500'

INSERT INTO cashback00 (valor) VALUES (10.00)

ALTER TABLE clientes ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cliente_cashback FOREIGN KEY (id_cashback) REFERENCES cashback(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that the table is populated with data.

The problem is that the column you are referencing, `cashback(id)`, is not the key of that table.

To make a foreign key, the column you reference should be the primary key of the referenced table.

So I reckon you must first do this:

```
ALTER TABLE cashback00 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

But that will not work if you have duplicate values in `id`. The primary key must be unique.

Also your foreign key needs to reference the table name you used `cashback00`, not `cashback`. Unless you also have a table named `cashback` which you have not shown in your question.

Comment: thanks for the attention shown... 
actually I misplaced the child table name for you.. sorry